# JSP page clears forward history in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, history, behavior, forward

I have a hosted JSP page. When I visit another page from jsp (lets say google.com) and hit the browser's back-button my jsp page reloads but instantly clears the forward history  (the forward button grays out and I cannot use history to access google.com). I was not aware of any functions in either java or javascript that could clear a browsers forward history. This behavior only happens in IE and not firefox or chrome.

Does anyone have any hint as to what could be possibly be happening in a jsp page that causes the forward history to clear on IE, but not firefox and chrome?

Comment: How do you make the refresh? Usually visiting a link resets the forward history. Why is the refresh required?

Comment: From "google.com" **we hit the browser back button** back to our jsp page.  As soon as our jsp page begins loading, the browser's forward button to google.com immediately grays out.  This same behavior is observed when navigating between jsp pages on our own site.

Comment: I think you could check the headers sent by the server and the behaviour of the page with disabled JavaScript.

Comment: Forward history clears every time user navigates. Might be your jsp is navigating itself (loading an url in an iframe, for example). I once used this trick (loading "about:blank" in a hidden iframe) to clear browser forward history.